# Unexpected result from acquiring toke from the Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory

I am working on client project where I need to get the user from Azure AD and need to store in the application database. For that, I have added the page to get the settings and button to test settings details. I am using below code to get the access token

```
  string authString = authnEndpoint + tenant;
  AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString);
  ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);  
  AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientCred);
  authenticationResult.AccessToken
```

**It is working fine in below scenario**

When entering the wrong details I am getting the exception on AcquireToken method whereas when I have given correct details it gives me access token

**It is not working in below scenario**

It is not working fine in reverse order that is When entering the correct details I am getting access token after that I am entering wrong details now it give me access token again. I can resolve this only when I am restarting the application

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "correct details"? Do you mean tenant, clientId, and clientSecret?

Comment: @JackZeng yes, your right. I mean tenant, clientId, and clientSecret details

Comment: The Problem is the token caching. I am doing some research to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the constructor `AuthenticationContext(String)` which have the Token Cache enabled by default. Hence, it will give you the token even if your inputs are not correct, within certain a mount of time. Here is a solution.

```
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, null);
```

Use constructor `AuthenticationContext(String, TokenCache)` instead. Setting TokenCache to be null, will disable the Token Cache.

Comment: if token cache disabled then, Do I need to get new access token for each time when i am requesting graph API?. I mean, Will it affect the access token expire time?

Comment: No, this will not affect the access token expire time. It just clears the local cache, which does not affect the server side.